# Select node and highlight its connections by feature ID in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have create a D3.js network graph. I want to select a node by its id and highlight it and its neighbors. I have the following code already

```
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});
//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}
```

But how do I use this for only one selected node selected by its feature id?

Comment: I am using reveal.js to create an html presentation. It always me to use D3.js transitions. So after loading the network graph. I would like to select a node by its id and highlight it and its neighbors.

Comment: `d3.select("#" + "nodeID")
 .transition().duration(500)
        .call(fade(.5));


function fade(opacity) {
        return function(d) {
            node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
            });

            link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
            });
        };
    }`

Comment: ive tried this but it fades out all nodes and links

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer:

```
d3.select("#nodeID")
    .transition().duration(500)
    .each(function(d){ //#nodeID is now selected as this
            node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
            });
            link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
            });

        });
```

I want to display labels for only nodes that are display. Any suggestions?